# How create dynamics CLBeaconRegion on iOS, Ibeacon

Tags: ibeacon, proximity, estimote

I have the info(Uuid, Major, Minor) of two beacons in my DB, and I want to create two CLBeaconRegion but dynamically, because there is the possibility of adding more beacons and create more CLBeaconRegion, I have this code:

```
          for i in 0 ... self.ArrayBeaconIDs.count-1 {
          let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(

                proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: self.ArrayBeaconIDs[i])!,
                major:  CLBeaconMajorValue(self.ArrayMajor[i])! ,minor:CLBeaconMajorValue(self.ArrayMinor[i])!
                , identifier: "teuchlitlan"
            )
            self.ArrayRegiones.append(beaconRegion)
        }
        for i in 0 ... self.ArrayRegiones.count-1 {
            self.ArrayRegiones[i].notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true
            self.ArrayRegiones[i].notifyOnEntry = true
            self.ArrayRegiones[i].notifyOnExit = true

            self.beaconManager.startMonitoring(for: self.ArrayRegiones[i])
            self.beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(in: self.ArrayRegiones[i])
            self.beaconManager.requestState(for: self.ArrayRegiones[i])
        }
```

but only detect the last region in the Array, How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ranging or monitoring multiple regions, the `identifier` field must be set to a unique string, as it is a key used to start, stop and replace the monitored region.  If you try to monitor or range two different regions with the same `identifier` field value, you effectively replace the previous region registration with the new one that has the same `identifier` value.

To fix this in your case, simply change the `identifier` value with a unique string.  You can generate one like so:

OLD:

```
proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: self.ArrayBeaconIDs[i])!,
                         major:  CLBeaconMajorValue(self.ArrayMajor[i])!,
                         minor:CLBeaconMajorValue(self.ArrayMinor[i])!, 
                         identifier: "teuchlitlan"
```

NEW:

```
proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: self.ArrayBeaconIDs[i])!,
                         major:  CLBeaconMajorValue(self.ArrayMajor[i])!,
                         minor:CLBeaconMajorValue(self.ArrayMinor[i])!, 
                         identifier: "teuchlitlan\(i)"
```

The second code snippet will add a numeric suffix to each region `identifier` so they are:

teuchlitlan0, teuchlitlan1, teuchlitlan2 ... etc

Comment: Thanks so mucho :D